# why the traefik did not match the url by the path

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I am using traefik 2.2.1 as my kubernetes ingress controller. Now I have a url need to forward, this is my traefik config right now:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2021-09-26T09:10:02Z'
  generation: 4
  name: uat-zhuolian-manage-route
  namespace: dabai-uat
  resourceVersion: '106700291'
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1/namespaces/dabai-uat/ingressroutes/uat-zhuolian-manage-route
  uid: d0b82fab-cd6a-49f0-96dc-f6c0f381bcc5
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`zhuolian-pro-manage.example.com`)
      services:
        - name: be-zhuolian-frontend
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`zhuolian-pro-manage.example.com`) && Path(`/service`)
      services:
        - name: soa-zhuolian-service
          port: 11032
```

what I want the traefik to do is that forward the example.com to `be-zhuolian-frontend` by default. If the request url contains `service`, for example the url `xxx.example.com/service/foo/bar`, forward to the backend service `soa-zhuolian-service`. but now when I request to the url from remote cloud host:

```
curl --header 'Host:zhuolian-pro-manage.example.com' http://172.19.104.230/service/zhuolian/report/user/captcha -L
```

shows error:

```
[root@fat001 ~]# curl --header 'Host:zhuolian-pro-manage.example.com' http://172.19.104.230/service/zhuolian/report/user/captcha -L
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

it seems the url with `service` keywords still route to the frontend service, what should I do to fix this problem and make the `service` match to the backend service successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `PathPrefix` not `path`, from official document:

> Use Path if your service listens on the exact path only. For instance,
> Path: /products would match /products but not /products/shoes.
>
> Use a *Prefix* matcher if your service listens on a particular base
> path but also serves requests on sub-paths. For instance, PathPrefix:
> /products would match /products but also /products/shoes and
> /products/shirts. Since the path is forwarded as-is, your service is
> expected to listen on /products.

so tweak the config like this:

```
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`zhuolian-pro-manage.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/service`)
      middlewares:
        - name: service-stripprefix
      services:
        - name: soa-zhuolian-service
          port: 11032
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`zhuolian-pro-manage.example.com`)
      services:
        - name: be-zhuolian-frontend
          port: 80
```